# Maximum estimate curve value to temporal GLMM

Tags: r, glmmtmb, glmm

I'd like to find a better way to calculate the maximum value of a temporal (my tempora variable is months `mes`) mixed GLM model using the `glmmTMB` package. But I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it. I'm using the following code:

```
#Packages
library(glmmTMB)
library(tidyverse)
library(inflection)
library(ggeffects)
theme_set(theme_bw())

# Dataset
d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/p_lineares.csv",h=T)


# Better GLMM comparing with several others eg. poisson, nbinom2 and ziGamma
m.c <- glmmTMB(N ~ poly(mes,2) + poly(prec,2) + (1 | mes), data = d,
               family = "nbinom1",
               ziformula = ~ 1)

# Find the max inflexion using bede: Bisection Extremum Distance Estimator Method 
ds_F <- cbind(x=d$mes,y=exp(predict(m.c)))
ds_F <- as.data.frame(ds_F)
bb=bede(ds_F$x,ds_F$y,1);bb
bb$iplast

# Plota o gráfico 
ggpredict(m.c, terms = "mes [all]") %>% plot(add.data = TRUE) + geom_vline(xintercept = bb$iplast, colour="red", linetype = "longdash") + labs(
      title = " ",
      x     = "Meses",
      y     = "Insects counts")
```

[image: bede]

Please, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `bede` appears to be looking for an *inflection point*, not a critical point ...

Comment: This is true Ben, I make some confusion about inflection and critical point. I'd like the critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want to account for the non-focal variables.  I'll use `emmeans`.

```r
library(emmeans)
predfun <- function(mval) {
   ee <- emmeans(m.c, ~mes, at = list(mes=mval))
   as.data.frame(ee)$emmean  ## extract predicted value
}
optimize(predfun, interval = c(2,15), maximum = TRUE)
```

If you want to be a little bit sloppier, you can predict at a large number of intermediate values and use `which.max()`:

```r
mval_vec <- seq(2, 12, length = 1000)
ee <- emmeans(m.c, ~mes, at = list(mes=mval_vec)) |> as.data.frame()
with(ee, mes[which.max(emmean)])
```

(By the way, using your provided data and code produces a completely different graph for me, one with the opposite curvature - it has its *minimum* near 7.5 and its maxima at either end, at 2 and 12)

Comment: Thank you very much Ben, I see this question about the graph now and I don't have a good explanation, because that's the same data set, but my MRE here is in GitHub and the graph is local.